# how to use callback on multiple functions in ajax reponse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my javascript code loader hides but it should hide on the last of the jax response.

```
function reverseGeocoding(lat,lng, callback){
    var url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse?format=json&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' +lng+' &zoom=18&addressdetails=1';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,                       
        crossDomain:true,
        success: function(response){
               fn1(response,mapobject);   //takes 30 seconds
               fn2(response,mapobject);   //takes 10 seconds
               fn3(response,mapobject);   //takes 30 seconds
               fn4(response,mapobject);   //takes 20 seconds
               fn5(response,mapobject);   //takes 30 seconds
               fn6(response,mapobject);   //takes 30 seconds
               fn7(response,mapobject);   //takes 40 seconds
               $("#loader").show();

        }
    });

}
```

but the problem is that loader show after response comes. i want to show loader after all  function call fn1,fn2,fn3,fn4,fn5,fn6,fn7. please help

Comment: Either setTimeout or code your custom functions to each have a callback and call on the next function. Obviously call the show method last.

Comment: Add your $("#loader").show(); inside the fn7 function at the end

Comment: thanks  francisco.preller for your reply but i know that i have to use calback for it but i dont know how to use it on multiple function complete.

Comment: So basically your fn1, fn2, etc functions are asynchronous and you want the $('#loader').show() to run after they have all returned?

Comment: @ SAM its not perfact answer I have to use callback.

Comment: @ ivarni yaa i have to show loader after all have returned.

Comment: You should look on promises and deferred objects http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/

Comment: @francisco.preller can u tell me how to use callback on custom functions and call on the next function.

Comment: I honestly think the deffered examples posted as answers already will be a much better option than using callbacks. To demonstrate, using 7 callbacks would end up with something like fn1(x, fn2()) etc etc, all the way up to function 7. Using deffered and promise statements will provide much cleaner and less complicated code in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`$.Deffered`**](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), particulalry [**`$.when`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [**`$.then`**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). Assuming in all of your functions you are performing an `$.ajax` request, they should look like this:

```
function f1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("f1 done")
        }
    });
}
```

Such function will return a `promise`, whicn can be then placed inside your callback using `$.when`:

```
 $.when(f1(), f2(), f3()).then(function () {
     console.log("all done!");
 });
```

[**Fiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmUeF/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery deferred object.

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();

    dfd
        .done( [ fn1, fn2 ], fn3, [ fn2, fn1 ] )
        .done(function( n ) {
            $( "p" ).append( n + " we're done." );
        });
```